# Filter query on array of embedded documents(3 levels) in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of diagrams. Each diagram has several blocks. And each block is having several ports, which in itself has multiple objects as fields.
So far i am only able to apply `$filter` or `$group` up to level 1 on blocks. I am unable to filter up to ports based on some condition.

The document structure is: Diagram

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "port": [
          {
            "portType": {
              "function": "input"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What i am trying to achieve is to get a list of all ports which have `input` as `portType.function` from the collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{"blocks.ports":{$filter:{input:"$blocks.ports",as:"ports",cond:{$in:["input","$$ports.portType.function"]}}}}}]);
```

Expected output : `list<Ports>` which have only `portType.function` as input.

Actual output: Returns all the documents which have at least one port as "input" along with all the other ports as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of `Port` objects you should use double `$unwind` stage, then `$match` for `blocks.port.portType.function` and finally extract only the ports using a `$project` stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$blocks"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$blocks.port"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "blocks.port.portType.function": "input"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      portType: "$blocks.port.portType",
    }
  }
])
```

If your `Port` object contains other fields you want to extract, like for example `Foo`, you have just to add those fields in the `$project` stage like

```
$project: {
    _id: 0,
    portType: "$blocks.port.portType",
    foo: "$blocks.port.foo"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It gave the complete list of ports for the given condition.

Comment: Using $project, i am getting result in nested structure `{"ports":{<first-key>: <first-value>, ...}},{"ports":{<first-key>: <first-value>, ...}}`. How can i get directly list of port object `{<port1>,<port2>,...}`

Comment: with `$project` you can structure the output as you want. With the query I provided you actually get a list of `Port` objects. You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NDRt82w289C).

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use two `$unwind` stages to flatten the arrays, followed by a `$match` stage like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$blocks"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$blocks.port"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "blocks.port.portType.function": "input"
    }
  }
])
```

result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "blocks": {
      "port": {
        "portType": {
          "function": "input"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/TOUCkCOSE7D](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TOUCkCOSE7D)

Comment: it worked. Thanks. Using $project got me exactly what i needed.